# Не работают ссылки на сайте. Как исправить?

Tags: android, wordpress

У меня есть сайт http://www.doverie2u.com.ua.
Когда захожу с телефона android, все отлично отображается, только ссылки не работают (не могу перейти на страницу статьи с главной страницы). На статьи невозможно зайти. На страницы "Контакты" не нажимается на телефоны. Сайт на wordpress. Почему так происходит? Как исправить?

Помогите, пожалуйста, может у кого-то есть какие-то предположения в какую сторону копать? Я не прошу выполнить работу за меня, а только дать мне подсказку!

Если Вы можете зайти и протестировать с Айфона или телефона на Windows Phone буду благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Айфоном или Винфоном не располагаю, но с андроида, как и вчера, всё нормально нажимается.

[image]